# Efficient way to append data to REDIS hash

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine, redis

I am doing some computing where I store the **results** in the REDIS database before it is sent to the database.

Currently I batch operations for size of 10k items per chunk which I process in separate GAE instance (single threaded computing using NodeJS), while the computing speed is really good, the PUSH action which performs `HSET` operations is taking a long time, so then it causes some delay in different threads (as REDIS is single threaded - **fyi** I am using Google REDIS Basic instance).

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it to be pushed faster (like in batch or somehting) than now?

```
const key = '123';
for (const [column, value] of results) {
   await this.appendRedisHashValue(key, column, value);
}

public async appendRedisHash(key: string, field: string, value: any) {
        const appendRedisHashAsync = promisify(this.redisClient.hset).bind(this.redisClient);
        return appendRedisHashAsync(key, field, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

As you can see, I am simply pushing each of the item one by one using `HSET` wondering if we can do some sort of `SQL transactions` and push for example 10k items in a single HSET transaction instead of appending REDIS Hash every single time.

Each of the chunk (10k items) has size of ~43MB after it is saved to the REDIS (so in total 100k items gives 430MB). For some architecture design **it must be stored in one single REDIS hash**.

Current speed (milliseconds), each of the job is running in parallel separate thread:

```
"push": 13608
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:26.045Z"

push": 13591,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:29.640Z"

"push": 15738,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:59.177Z"

"push": 21208,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:44.432Z"

"push": 13332,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:28.303Z"

"push": 10598,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:44.455Z"

"push": 27249,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:51:58.458Z"

"push": 36270,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:52:00.708Z"

"push": 25106,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:52:02.234Z"

"push": 12845,
"finishedAt": "2020-05-08T22:52:02.254Z"
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: ```mset``` doesn't meet the requirement, as this is for simple key/value store not for hashes, not sure about the pipeline, do you have some example?

Comment: Did you take a look at Redis pipelining: https://redis.io/topics/pipelining? It helps send a series of commands to Redis in one connection instead of sending individual commands in succession there by reducing RTT (Round Trip Time) for each command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it using HSET and HMSET over 10000 values, and I created simple bulk function  to handle the records, from the simple data perspective it looks fantastic, let see how it is going to end in production environment.

While `npm redis` library didn't like hset to put it in this way, the `hmset` did work tho which is weird.

```
const myarr = [];
const values = 10000;
for(let i = 0; i < values; i++) {
    myarr.push(`key${i}`);
    myarr.push('value');
}
await this.bulkRedisHash('myTest', myarr);
/*
    [Nest] 17800   - 2020-05-09 18:45:30   [FinalizeTaskService] starting +5ms
    [Nest] 17800   - 2020-05-09 18:45:30   [FinalizeTaskService] finished +21ms
 */
for (let i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        await this.appendRedisHash('myTest2', myarr[i-1], myarr[i]);
    }
}
/*
   [Nest] 18396   - 2020-05-09 18:49:08   [FinalizeTaskService] starting +4ms
   [Nest] 18396   - 2020-05-09 18:49:09   [FinalizeTaskService] finished +795ms
*/

public async appendRedisHash(key: string, field: string, value: any) {
    const appendRedisHashAsync = promisify(this.redisClient.hset).bind(this.redisClient);
    return appendRedisHashAsync(key, field, value);
}

public async bulkRedisHash(key: string, keyValue: string[]) {
    const appendRedisHashAsync = promisify(this.redisClient.hmset).bind(this.redisClient);
    return appendRedisHashAsync(key, [...keyValue]);
}
```

To bulk append

Comment: JFYI, as per the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hmset), `HMSET` is considered deprecated since Redis 4.0.0

Comment: Yes I know, but current ```npm redis``` package doesn't have support for HSET with the similar functionality, for now it does support ```key,column,value``` only.

Comment: Does it support pipelining?

Comment: No, the ```ioredis```, does I think.

Comment: Yeah, even Redis.io has [starred](https://redis.io/clients#nodejs) it. If you have the luxury to switch to another library, then you can try pipelining out. Sample code [here](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#pipelining).

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is calling hset multiple times with a single key/value. which is bad because of the round trip latency.

doing it to 10k key/value will be 10k round trips.

you can use `hset` with multiple key/value so it will be a single trip to redis. eg

`hset field1 value1 field2 value2 field3 value3`

Comment: Yes, was thinking about it actually, but not sure if this is possible by 'redis' library which I am using, I think I also found a ioredis library which supports pipelines and i think would be the best candidate for this operations.